# Swift - SWRevealViewController change programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on a swift project and I'm using SWRevealViewController (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). I got it done to show few items inside the side menu.

My question now is: Is it possible and how is it  possible to disable or better to skip on possible item in the side menu for some special cases.

Example:

Case-1: The side menu will have 3 items
Item-1
Item-2
Item-3

Case-2: The same side menu will have just 2 out of 3 items
Item-1
Item-3

So is it possible to hide/skip one item in the side menu with code?

Comment: Is your side menu a `TableViewController` ? If answer is Yes the cells are static or dynamic ? You have to provide more information about the structure of your side menu

Comment: Im using SWRevealViewController, they have menu items hard-coded in the storyboard. To do what you're asking, you'll need to set the menu items in the view controller as an array of items.

Comment: Ok thanks mattkc7. Do you know how I can set this items in the view controller as an array of items, and add this then to the SWRevealviewController?